# Can't seem to get python to work

Tags: apache-2.2, python

I'm just starting out in Python.  The Python interpreter works from the command line (I have 2.4.3), but I can't seem to get Apache to execute Python scripts.  All I end up with is a blank screen and nothing in the Apache error logs.

I enabled Python via the Plesk control panel. Here's the snippet that was generated in the httpd.include:

```
<Files ~ (\.py$)>
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler   mod_python.cgihandler
</Files>
```

My test script is one of the examples that comes with the Python downloads at http://python.org/download/

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

"""CGI test 1 - check server setup."""

# Until you get this to work, your web server isn't set up right or
# your Python isn't set up right.

# If cgi0.sh works but cgi1.py doesn't, check the #! line and the file
# permissions.  The docs for the cgi.py module have debugging tips.

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("<h1>Hello world</h1>")
print("<p>This is cgi1.py")
```

That wasn't working, so I changed `#!/usr/local/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python` which is what `which python` tells me but the results were the same.

Like I said, I'm ending up with a blank page. No errors that I know of, unless I'm checking the wrong error log (I'm checking the Apache error log).  I'm on a MediaTemple (dv) running CentOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by replacing the code:

```
print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
```

to

```
print("Content-type: text/html")
print("\n\n")
```

**Edit**

`print()` => will print `()` if you run from the terminal

`print`   => will print a line break character '\n' . See the doc [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html) (Look up for print)

Comment: That works, thanks!  So does all output have to be prefaced by `print("Content-type: text/html")` if I want it to show up in the browser?

Comment: Yes, if you want to return some HTML, you have to set it as text/html, if you want some plain text, the content-type is text/plain . See a list of content type at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type

Comment: Cool thanks. Coming from PHP, it's strange/unexpected to have to set a content type.

Comment: It's because "text/html" is set by default in php. You can see it in php.ini. In this file it has the following set:
default_mimetype = "text/html"

Answer (score 0):

A.) Make sure you can run your script from the command line.  B.) Try adding an extra print() after the first print().

Comment: Yup, it works from the command line